# Need info on the WebService::Discord::Webhook Perl module

Tags: perl, discord

I'm trying to use the WebService::Discord::Webhook  Perl module to post to my Discord WebHook and have the basic "content" value working but I want to attach a file and no matter what I try I get this error:

```
    code: 400 Bad Request
    content: {"content": ["Could not interpret \"{'file': 'News.txt', 'content': 'News Report  - 10/02/2023', 'data': '        -=[  EMPIRE NEWS  ]=-\\n::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::\\n!       \"All the news that fits, we print.\"      !\\n::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::\\n       Mon Oct  2 22:56:38 2023\\n\\n\\nRelative calm prevails.\\n\\nThe details of Empire news since Mon Oct  2 22:48:55 2023\\n\\nNo news at the moment...\\n'}\" as string."]} at ./poststats line 74.
```

I am trying to call it as:

```
my %NewsHash = (
content    => "News Report  - $CurDate",
file       => "News.txt",
data       => "$file_content"
);
my $hash_ref = \%NewsHash;
$webhook->execute( $hash_ref );
```

### Can someone provide a example of the file call for me to work with?

I changed the definition like this:

```
my %NewsHash = {
content    => "News Report - $CurDate",
file       => {
name       => "News.txt",
data       => "$file_content"
              }
};
$webhook->execute( %NewsHash );
```

And now I get this error:

```
PARAMETER ERROR: Execute request missing required parameters (must have at least content, embed, or file) at ./poststats line 82.
```

Comment: Based on the documentation `execute` expects a hash, not a hash ref as you try (and you've tried differently before the edit). So it should be `$webhook->execute(content => ..., file => { name => ..., data => ... });`.

Comment: Looked at source. Confirmed what Steffen said. `$webhook->execute( $hash_ref );` is equivalent to `$webhook->execute( content => $hash_ref );`, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;` or equivalent. In the second question, you're doing the equivalent of `my %NewsHash => ( "HASH(0x99999)" => undef );`

Answer (score 1):

`->execute` expects a list of key-value pairs, not a reference to a hash.

```perl
$webhook->execute(
   content => "News Report - $CurDate",
   file    => ...,
   ...
);
```

```perl
my @params = (
   content => "News Report - $CurDate",
   file    => ...,
   ...
);

$webhook->execute( @params );
```

```perl
my %params = (
   content => "News Report - $CurDate",
   file    => ...,
   ...
);

$webhook->execute( %params );
```